# PHP Hashtable array optimisation

Tags: php, optimization, hashtable

I made a PHP app which was taking about ~0.0070sec for execution. Now, I added a hashtable array with about 2000 values. Suddenly the time for execution has gone up to ~0.0700 secs. Almost 10 times the previous value.

I tried commenting out the part where I was **searching inside** the hashtable array (but array was still left defined). Still, the execution time remains about ~0.0500secs.

Array is something like:

```
$subjectinfo = array(
        'TPT753' => 'Industrial Training',
        'TPT801' => 'High Polymeric Engineering',
        'TPT802' => 'Corrosion Engineering',
        'TPT803' => 'Decorative ,Industrial And High Performance Coatings',
        'TPT851' => 'Project');
```

Is there any way to optimize this part?

I cannot use Database as I am running this app on Google app engine which is still not supporting JDO database for php.

Some more code from the app:

```
function getsubjectinfo($name)
    {
        $subjectinfo = array(
        'TPT753' => 'Industrial Training',
        'TPT801' => 'High Polymeric Engineering',
        'TPT802' => 'Corrosion Engineering',
        'TPT803' => 'Decorative ,Industrial And High Performance Coatings',
        'TPT851' => 'Project');

    $name = str_replace("-", "", $name);
    $name = str_replace(" ", "", $name);
    if (isset($subjectinfo["$name"]))
        return "(".$subjectinfo["$name"].")";
    else
        return "";
   }
```

Then I am using the following statement 2-3 times in the app:

```
echo $key." ".$this->getsubjectinfo($key)
```

Comment: Are you constructing this array only once in your program?

Comment: yes. This array will remain contant for weeks...

Comment: @hiprakhar: That's not what I asked.

Comment: @jon I have declared this array only once in my project. Searching inside this array 2 times throughout the app lifetime.

Comment: If every key has TPT in it, try to make the array with integer indices without TPT. Integer indices will work faster

Comment: It's perfectly normal for execution time to be prolonged as the dataset grows. Also, it's still within reasonable time that humans cannot notice (7 milliseconds is really nothing). You could use APC to improve performance by caching PHP opcode itself if APC is available to you, but other than that I really don't see the reason to try to optimize this code. Your logic about execution also might be flawed, it doesn't necessarily mean if you increase the array to 20k values that the execution will rise linearly.

Comment: @stam Thanks for the suggestion. But all keys do not necessarily have TPT, they may be TOE362, AGS612 etc. I have sorted them in ascending order, but wonder if it helped. Right now I have defined array inside a class function, will using a constructor improve it?

Comment: @Furicane, the way I read it, the 7ms is when there are 20k values in the array. To rephrase the question (the way I'm interpreting it): is there a way to keep an array in memory and accessible to multiple instances of a php script?

Comment: @hiprakhar Of course it will! You are now constructing the array on *every* `getsubjectinfo()` call. Don't do this

Comment: @Furicane Its hurting that one array searching part of app is 10 times costlier than rest of the app... I want to keep the CPU utilization minimum to save GAE hours and hosting expenses!

Comment: @jswolf19 Bingo! thats the question.

Comment: @hiprakhar can you use memcached on the server?

Comment: @everyone Oh my ghosh! I revised my code to use a constructor to define the array and voila! things are back to normal.. execution time is back to 0.0050secs!! @stam Yes it worked! But I dont think its because the array is getting constructed on every getsubjectinfo() call, because, as I mentioned I ran my app _without calling getsubjectinfo() even once_

Comment: you can see it live here: http://prakhargoel.com/projects/viewresults/showresult.php?university=uptu&course=btech&year=btech_final_year2010&rollno=0602710066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getsubjectinfo($name)
{
    $subjectinfo = array(
    'TPT753' => 'Industrial Training',
    'TPT801' => 'High Polymeric Engineering',
    'TPT802' => 'Corrosion Engineering',
    'TPT803' => 'Decorative ,Industrial And High Performance Coatings',
    'TPT851' => 'Project');
// ..
}
```

This way the array is created *everytime* you call the function. Consider using a static variable here

```
function getsubjectinfo($name)
{
    static $subjectinfo = array(
    'TPT753' => 'Industrial Training',
    'TPT801' => 'High Polymeric Engineering',
    'TPT802' => 'Corrosion Engineering',
    'TPT803' => 'Decorative ,Industrial And High Performance Coatings',
    'TPT851' => 'Project');
// ..
}
```

And as a sidenote: You can also use a SQLite-Database :)

Update: An OOP approach

```
class MyClass {
    public static $subjectnames = array(
      'TPT753' => 'Industrial Training',
      'TPT801' => 'High Polymeric Engineering',
      'TPT802' => 'Corrosion Engineering',
      'TPT803' => 'Decorative ,Industrial And High Performance Coatings',
      'TPT851' => 'Project');

    public function getsubjectinfo($name) {
        $name = str_replace("-", "", $name);
        $name = str_replace(" ", "", $name);
        if (isset(self::$subjectnames["$name"]))
            return "(".self::$subjectnames["$name"].")";
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: @kingchurch Thanks! I am doing almost the same by using constructor to define the array.

Comment: Dont see any constructor and it would not change anything: `$subjectinfo` is a local variable and will get created in a method everytime its call too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using integers as keys into your table.

"But all keys do not necessarily have TPT, they may be TOE362, AGS612 etc. I have sorted them in ascending order, but wonder if it helped."

Hash your original strings into numeric data, and use that output as your hash keys.  Yes, there is a constant-time penalty involved per access (for the extra hash), but if your final data set is large enough, I suspect this may outperform letting PHP use string keys directly.

If all else fails, write the performance sensitive code in C and compile it as a PHP extension.  No, better yet, write the whole app in C.  Better yet, use direct machine code for everything.  Or wire a breadboard with your desired logic!  Reference: http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: Thanks the comic strip.. liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

Lesson of the day learnt- Defining large arrays in the class constructor can speed up the things.

I modified the code as:

```
class myclass
{
    var $subjectnames = array();
    function myclass()
    {
        $this->subjectnames = array(
    'TPT753' => 'Industrial Training',
    'TPT801' => 'High Polymeric Engineering',
    'TPT802' => 'Corrosion Engineering',
    'TPT803' => 'Decorative ,Industrial And High Performance Coatings',
    'TPT851' => 'Project');
    }


function getsubjectinfo($name)
    {
        //$subjectinfo = array();
        $name = str_replace("-", "", $name);
        $name = str_replace(" ", "", $name);
        if (isset($this->subjectnames["$name"]))
            return "(".$this->subjectnames["$name"].")";
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I once read that you can optimize such a static array configuration via serialize/unserialize.

Inject in your source code the serialized version of the array. It will be a string.

Use unserialize(..) to dynamically build the array.

Urban legend says It might save some parsing time.

another thing you can try is to use object properties instead of array keys.

$obj->TRV3463 may be faster than array access.